# Как сделать dots indicator вне ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Мне нужно сделать status dots вне ViewPager. Это означает, что мне нужно сделать точки отдельными экземплярами класса customView, которые можно включить в макет Activity в XML. Поэтому мне нужно реализовать необходимые для этого  конструкторы. Каждая точка должна поддерживать переключение между выбранным / не выбранным состоянием. Понятия не имею, как это сделать. Я использую ViewPager с View (не с фрагментами)

Answer (score 1):

Ну ViewPager или не ViewPager, вам нужно писать свою кастомную View. Скорее всего это будет не тривиальная задача, потому как написание кастомных View всегда не просто.

Я бы сделал некоторую [CompoundView](https://medium.com/@Sserra90/android-writing-a-compound-view-1eacbf1957fc) в которой бы создавал каждый dot в зависимости от заданных параметров. Дальше при самом простом кейсе вы можете просто играться их сменой окраски (темы или даже заменой на отдельный dot).

Писать тут не мало и решения вам никто не даст скорее всего.

Рекомендую почитать:

- [Создание собственной View под Android – может ли что-то пойти не так?](https://habr.com/ru/post/321890/)
- [Андроид — кастомные View или ToggleButton 4x4](https://habr.com/ru/post/254527/)
- [Как создать сustom View для Android](https://codeandlife.ru/android/1-creating-custom-android-views-part-1.html)

Это просто статьи на тему написания кастомных View, чтоб понять как это вообще работает.

Можно попробовать посмотреть решения с теми же dots-ами к ViewPager-ам и переписать под себя. [Вот одна из таких либ](https://github.com/tommybuonomo/dotsindicator).

Comment: спасибо за рекомендации